# dom elements ID's and CLASSes

Tags: html, css, dom

If I have an element like this one for example:

```
<input type="text" class="someTextBox" id="someTextBoxID" />
```

... does it matter if class is placed before id? If I had to guess I'd say no, but then again I wonder if there are any rules regarding that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no rules for the ordering of attributes in HTML.

You can put them in any order you like.

Comment: I agree in general, but IMO `type` should always come first for an input.